# Ground pour on pcb battery holder?

Tags: current, pcb-design, ground

I'm designing a **battery holder pcb for 4 18650 Lithium Batteries** in series with max output **15A**.
The board has **2 layers**. The **bottom** is just a **GND** pour. On the right there is the "**battery pack out**" terminal and the **balance connector**.

I am **not sure**, if I should use a **dedicated polygon for GND pin of the battery pack** on the top layer, so that:

- the **current is guided to the best path** and **does not follow narrower paths** (see **green arrows** in second image), which would **heat up**
- this GND **noisy path** (due to high current) stays **a bit isolated from the balance connector traces**

**As first option** I've created the design below, where the GND polygon (marked **yellow**) is separate but not isolated from the surrounding not-high-current GND pour, thanks to vias going to the bottom layer (GND); the vias are placed away from the current shortest path:

[image: first option pcb]

The **second option** (below), is just a ground pour also on the top layer:
[image: second option pcb]

**Which one is the best? Or maybe there are better alternatives, like no ground pours at all?**

Schematic:

[image: schematic]

Thanks

Comment: One question: Why do you think current will take only narrower path in the second image? For the current to flow, it will take least resistance path. In your second image, I can see there is a bigger ground pour below. That would mean maximum current will be flowing from there.

Comment: I am not saying the current will only take the narrower paths. As the battery holder has SMD pads and (for the moment) there are only few vias, I'd expect most of the current to stay on the top layer, following the most direct green arrow between the GND pin of the holder and the battery terminal. Anyway, which design is the better? And what about signal integrity?